# Extract 3 consecutive digits using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, pandas

To extract the 3 consecutive digits, I tried:

```
df['col'].str.findall(r"\d\d\d").str[0]
```

and

```
df['col'].str.findall(r"[0-9]{3}").str[0]
```

but both returned results which are not actually consecutive but with other characters in between. For example, for `GF-01-1 G.888 SSRS`, I want to extract `888` but in the abovementioned methods both returned `01-1`.

In another example of `MMS1-CG343 SSRS`, I want to extract `343`, instead `NaN` was returned.

Comment: Consider adding a minimum reproducible example, because as pointed out in the answer below, the issue could not be reproduced and hence we cant really help since we cant examine the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem:

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                    A
0  GF-01-1 G.888 SSRS
1     MMS1-CG343 SSRS

In [3]: df.A.str.findall(r"\d\d\d")
Out[3]:
0    [888]
1    [343]
Name: A, dtype: object

In [4]: df.A.str.findall(r"\d\d\d").str[0]
Out[4]:
0    888
1    343
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Im not familiar with this, but could it be because OP has added `.str[0]` at the end ? I notice that the return is a list for you, so perhaps he intended to only add indexing at the end?

Comment: Nope. See my edit.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess OP should provide a minimum reproducible example